# how to change the menu depending on the width of the screen?

Tags: reactjs

I apologize for my English using a translator.
I use React.js.
I have a component "header" that accepts two other components -  and .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Header.module.css';
import MainLogo from '../MainLogo/MainLogo';
import NavMenu from '../NavMenu/NavMenu';
import BurgerButton from '../BurgerMenu/BurgerButton';
import BurgerMenu from '../BurgerMenu/BurgerMenu';class Header extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <nav className={styles.navBar}>
          <MainLogo />
          <NavMenu />
        </nav>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

I also created a separate component .
I want to get this markup option: if the screen size is <= 420px, the  component should be rendered in the header. With a screen width >420px, the  component should be displayed.
I understand that the question is very banal, but I have not yet found an elegant solution.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. using an external library is not suitable.

Comment: "if the screen size is <= 420px, the component should be rendered in the header. With a screen width >420px, the component should be displayed" what does it means for you?

Comment: I need this result - screen width less 420px in the header is rendered Component 1 (BurgerButton), when screen width more 420px in the header is rendered Component 2 (NavMenu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`react-media`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media) to render components conditionally based on the screen's size.

In your case, it would look something like this (adapt for your specific markup)

```
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <nav className={styles.navBar}>
          <MainLogo />
          <NavMenu />
          <Media query={{ maxWidth: 420 }}>
            {matches => <MyComponent /> // Component is in the header}
          </Media>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <Media query={{ minWidth: 421 }}>
        {matches => <MyComponent /> // Component is outside of the header}
      </Media>
```

Comment: Fine! this is what i needed! Thank you very much!